vertically centering stacked images
I was working on a stack of three images that should appear sequentially, I followed this post to get the gist of it. The end result is fine; however I wish I could vertically align the second and the third image so that they are central aligned in respect to the first (see drawing).
This is a MWE for the whole frame, where I set the structure for three points I will touch. The incriminated part is the one with three duck images. Thanks in advance!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\ifnum\c@framenumber>1%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=-2pt]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=\beamerheadheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transuncover<4-5>
\transuncover<7-8>
\frametitle<1-7>{Title 1}
\frametitle<8-13>{Title 2}
\framesubtitle<8-10>{sub 1}
\framesubtitle<11-13>{sub 2}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.95\textheight}

\only<1-8>{
\only<1-2>{
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics<1->[width=.55\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{itemize}
            \visible<2>{\item point 1}
        \end{itemize}
}
\only<3-4>{
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics<3->[width=.55\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{itemize}
            \visible<4>{\item point 2}
        \end{itemize}
}
\only<5-7>{
        \begin{figure}
                \hbox{\hspace*{0.1in}\includegraphics<5->[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\hspace{-2.15in}\includegraphics<6->[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\hspace{-2.35in}\includegraphics<7->[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}
        \end{figure}
        \vskip -.25in
        \begin{itemize}
            \visible<7>{\item point 3}
        \end{itemize}
}
}

\only<8-10>{
\includegraphics<8->[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\vskip -.05in
\includegraphics<9->[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\visible<10>{\begin{exampleblock}{Issue 1}
    \centering exp 1
\end{exampleblock}}
}

\only<11-13>{
\includegraphics<11->[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\vskip -.05in
\includegraphics<12->[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\visible<13>{\begin{exampleblock}{Issue 2}
    \centering exp 2
\end{exampleblock}}
}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Wrap the image inclusion with \raisebox  like so: \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics...}.

@AlexG thanks. Indeed, this works but as my code was already quite messy in the end I decided to clean it up a bit using the TikZ approach.

I would use TikZ:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \node[anchor=west,visible on=<2->] at (1,0) {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \node[anchor=west,visible on=<3->] at (2,0) {\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



thanks a lot! Really neat solution.
